# How to override the default orientation of another app?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a background service that detects when an app is launched and automatically changes its orientation to the user's desired orientation by drawing a system window on top of it (got the idea and code from an old post on SO).

So inside the service here is how it works:

```
View orientationChanger;
WindowManager wm;

wm = (WindowManager) content.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);

orientationChanger = new LinearLayout(content);
orientationChanger.setClickable(false);
orientationChanger.setFocusable(false);
orientationChanger.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
orientationChanger.setLongClickable(false);

orientationLayout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

orientationLayout.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

orientationChanger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
wm.addView(orientationChanger, orientationLayout);
```

The above code should force the running app into portrait mode. Here's the problem: Take trying to force the game Geometry Dash into portrait mode (the game by default only allows landscape mode). If the above code is run ***after*** Geometry Dash is launched then this is what the game will look like:

[What it should NOT look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkeqT.jpg)

However if the above code is run ***before*** Geometry Dash is launched then this is what it will look like:

[What it should really look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0qe6.jpg)

The latter is what the game should look like in portrait mode. However I am unable to achieve this since I can't run the above code snippet until after I detect that the user has launched the game. So what possible way is there to get the second result instead of the first? Is there perhaps a way to recreate the game from my background service similar to the `recreate()` method that you can use in your own activities?

Answer (score 0):

Emmm....

Why don't you just follow the Android changing possition support?

So use correct flag for activity orientation in the androidManifest and create 2 layouts for the view: one portrait and the other one placed in the landscape layouts folder.

Isn't it simpler than trying to do it dynamically in the activity code?

EDIT: sorry I misunderstood....
If you want to "force portrait". Doesn't flag for orientation in manifest for this particular activity  works?

Comment: I'm trying to force orientation change on other apps.

Comment: The problem is that the code posted above only gets executed after the app is launched. I think what's happening is that the target app (Geometry Dash in this example) is automatically detecting what orientation the device is capable of during its launch. If it detects the device is capable of landscape mode then it fixes the screen to landscape mode and does not allow a change to portrait mode. But if at launch the target app detects that the screen is stuck in portrait mode then it can launch in portrait mode (the dev of the target app obviously did not intend for portrait mode to be used).

Comment: So as you can see from the first screenshot, the result of forcing an orientation change after the app has already launched is that the app will not be generated correctly since it thinks the display is in landscape mode. The only way to inform it that the screen must be in portrait mode is if it is told at launch that the device is fixed in portrait mode. That's why the code I posted above needs to be run before the app is launched not after.

Comment: So my random guess/solution is to recreate the target app right after the above code is executed so that it's able to detect that the device is fixed in portrait mode. By "recreate" I mean close it and launch it again. I don't know if it's even possible to recreate another app.

Comment: Any ideas?  .  :)

Comment: To be honest. I doubt it is possible. Google tries to separate apps as much it is possible. To avoid for example hacker controlling banking app of the user. So I don't think they allowed app's developer to do this...

Comment: Ok but I've seen how an accessibility service can block access to certain apps. And luckily for me the background service that I'm using to detect when an app is launched so I can change its orientation is an accessibility service. So if an accessibility service can block a user from opening an app, surely that's a capability I can use. Like for example detect when the user launches the app, block it for an instant so that the code above can run, and then immediately launch the app. Any idea how to get an accessibility service to do this (as in block the launch of an app)?

Comment: Also how do some apps (like Greenify I think) force close other apps?